# Data isn't saved in Database

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to save country name in database.

[image]
After clicking the button this is showing the filed name is blank.

[image]

html:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="country_name" placeholder="Country name">
                        @error('country_name')
                        <span class="text-danger">{{$message}}</span>
                        @enderror
```

Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
   {
       $this->validate($request,[
        'name'=>'required|unique:divisions',
       ],
       [
           'name.unique' => 'Division Name Already Exists'
       ]);
       $divisions = new Division();
       $divisions->country_name = $request->country_name;
       $divisions->subcontinent_id = $request->subcontinent_id;
       $divisions->save();
        return back();
   }
```

Model

```
class Division extends Model
{
   protected $fillable = [
      'country_name', 'subcontinent_id'
  ];
   public function subcontinent()
   {
      return $this->belongsTo(Subcontinent::class);
   }

}
```

I triple checked for typos and tried different html format. The data isn't saving. I am confused why this is happening. I am noob at eloquent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your validation. As I cannot see `name` in your inputs, change `name` to `country_name`:

```
$this->validate($request,[
        'country_name'=>'required|unique:divisions',
       ],
       [
           'country_name.unique' => 'Division Name Already Exists'
       ]);
```

Your form has some errors, if you want to see the errors, you have multiple options, one of them is adding below code in your blade to display all errors.

```
@foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
    <div>{{$error}}</div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you, I miss-typed the name. Edited here also. Now It isn't showing any error but still the data isn't saving in the database.

Comment: You mean that after submission and redirecting back, there isn't any error in your page?

Comment: Yeah . It solved after changing $this->validate($request,[
        'country_name'=>'required|unique:divisions',
       ],
       [
           'country_name.unique' => 'Division Name Already Exists'
       ]); to  $this->validate($request,[
        'country_name'=>'required|unique:divisions',
       ]);

Comment: But thank you It would still show the name error if you did point it out.

Answer (score 0):

your input name is country_name not name so please change it where you are validating it

```
'country_name'=>'required|unique:divisions',
```

instead of

```
'name'=>'required|unique:divisions',
```